# Why div in a form is a problem for react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a following button which is connected to recaptcha according to docs

```js
<Button
  onClick={() => setShowSpinner(true)}
  size="lg"
  className="g-recaptcha"
  data-sitekey="XYZ"
  data-callback="handleFormSend"
  data-action='submit'
>
  {showSpinner && <Spinner
    as="span"
    animation="grow"
    size="sm"
    role="status"
    aria-hidden="true"
  />}
  Send
</Button>
```

I don't understand why in chrome I got

> "Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a `<div>` in `<form>`."

Of course I checked HTML code and don't see any div? In Mozilla there is no warning.

I use next and react.

What may be wrong?

Comment: The `Spinner` component probably renders as a `<div>`. I have no idea why Next/React has a problem with that.

Comment: Is this a Next.js app? This sounds like a SSR/hydration related issue. Can you show us the full code, including where the `form`  element is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 16 warning "warning.js:36 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350360/react-16-warning-warning-js36-warning-did-not-expect-server-html-to-contain-a)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a SSR/hydration issue. Try removing spaces between tags.

```js
<Button
  onClick={() => setShowSpinner(true)}
  size="lg"
  className="g-recaptcha"
  data-sitekey="XYZ"
  data-callback="handleFormSend"
  data-action='submit'
>
  {showSpinner &&
    <Spinner
      as="span"
      animation="grow"
      size="sm"
      role="status"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
  }
  Send
</Button>
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874539/1980034)

Comment: Just vote close as duplicate.